# Refresh download of pdf files

Tags: pdf, caching, hyperlink

In the top right social media widget on [this page](http://kowanyamariverhouse.com.au)
there is a link to a pdf file titled CURRENT ROAD REPORT.

This pdf is updated hourly 24 hours a day and it keeps the same URL.

Is there a way to stop browsers caching this download link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a dynamic get-parameter (e.g. a timestamp) to the link to bypass any cache. In PHP this could be done like this:

```
<a href="link.pdf?<?=time();?>">link</a>
```

If you have access to the server that delivers the file you could also define the specific cache information through the webserver.